# using math.log(var) in python

Tags: python, math, logarithm, natural-logarithm

I think if I'd know the math behind it I might have figured it out by myself.

When I call `math.log10(0.0000000000001)` I get `-13`. But how do I convert this back into `0.0000000000001`? and how i'd handle it when using `math.log(0.0000000000001)`?

Both ways, the fundamental, arithmetic one and the one using a built-in python function would interest me.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = math.log10(0.0000000000001)
b = 10 ** a
```

Comment: sorry, i edited my question. what is when math.log() is used instead of math.log10 ?

Comment: @bngschmnd - math.log uses base e, instead of base 10. So, math.exp() is the inverse of math.log()

Answer (score 0):

[math.log()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.log) takes two parameter, a number and a base. Default value is [e (mathematical constant)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), a special constant which tends to 2.71828.

You can get the number by evaluating ***base to the power log_value***

```
>>> a = math.log(10)
>>> a
2.302585092994046
>>> 2.71828**a
9.999984511610785
```

If I would take `e`'s value with higher precision, I can get the result close to 10.

Or, you can use [math.exp()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.exp)

```
>>>math.exp(a)
10.000000000000002
```

You can also use [math.pow()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pow)

```
>>> math.pow(2.71828,a)
9.999984511610785
```